# Show evaluation steps in PyParsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642650/how-to-evaluate-a-custom-math-expression-in-python) I was told about [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) as a way of evaluating custom math expressions. I'm still interested in using it, but in order to do so, I need to be able to retrieve a number of evaluation sub-steps. For example, in the example file [dice2.py](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/dice2.py), for the roll "4d20+5.5+4d6.takeHighest(3)", I would like something like:

```
4d20 + 5.5 + 4d6.takeHighest(3)
[2,6,13,18] + 5.5 + [2,2,5,6].takeHighest(3)
39 + 5.5 + [2,5,6]
44.5 + 13
57.5
```

So far I've been unable to find any way of retrieving this information. Is this possible? If so, how might I get it?

Comment: If you look at what is returned from expr.parseString(test) you will note that number evaluation is not performed by pyparsing in dice2.py.